# Folder hidden in Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: visual-studio

I have a class library project in Visual Studio 2017 and when I want to create a folder with a specific name it tells me that I can not because it already exists and I do not see that folder either in the project in Visual Studio or in the file browser in the folder where the project is saved. Where does VS search that folder to tell me that it already exists?

Any idea please

Regards

Comment: Click the "Show All Files" toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window so you can now also see subdirectories that don't have any project items.  You probably want to right-click it next and choose "Include in project", hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have clicked in Show All files to see the folder and I have included it to project